# Programming language with native code support, No framework (I write the framework)

Tags: programming-languages, scripting-languages

I'm looking for a programming language. It should be an easy language to learn, and should have a Garbage Collector. It should be a basic language with features like basic types (integer, boolean), arrays and etc, and I should write the framework.

It is for a game editor I want to write. The editor's designer will write the code of the UI in this programming language. The framework will be a 2D graphics and audio framework, and in the future it'll be 3D too.

I thought about the new Go language, but it doesn't have much support and theres no binding to OpenGL and etc.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: why the requirement for compiling to native code? Judging by what you are building I don't see why that is a requirement. You're leaving out many good choices, especially if "easy" is one of your criteria. Tcl, Python, Ruby would all make your task easier. Are you concerned about deployment? Some scripting languages (for example. Tcl) make it trivial to wrap up files into a single executable).

Comment: Because there are no good answers that really fit my requirements, I removed the native code compilation requirement.

Comment: Holy moving target, Batman! So what was missing from Lua?

Answer (score 4):

The obvious two are [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) or [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B). However, [D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_(programming_language)) is closer to Java and C# given that it has a garbage collector in the standard, as well as an alternative standard library that is fairly closer to Java than the C++ standard library. The downside with D is that they tools are not as mature as C++ or C and the community isn't as large.

The obvious solution though it to look down the list of [compiled languages on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language) and see which you like the look of.

Comment: Nice catch with D. I first thought it would be the next gen low level language. How ever, Go will probably kill it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, that's a fairly broad question and without more specific requirements it is difficult to give a focused answer, but it sounds like C (or C++) would fit the bill for you. The languages you described all owe their syntax to C. C will compile to native code. C is basic language in that there is not much to learn beyond the basic syntax and it has all the basic primitives that you require.

Now that you've added the requirement of a garbage collected language, I suppose that you could try [Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_Programming_Language), but that language is not mature and there's always a risk there.

Comment: I'm looking for something easier than C or C++.

Comment: WHat's the definition of easier? C--?

Comment: What do you mean by "easier"?

Comment: C and C++ don't support Garbage Collector.

Comment: @unknown: Well, that's an edit that you made after my response.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to manage memory all by yourself like C or C++, you can try the new [Go](http://golang.org) language. It compiles to native code (albeit for Linux and MacOSX only for now) and comes with a basic framework that can be easily replaced with your own framework.

It has a [very active user base](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/topics), so IMO it is possible to mature quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Enjoy a challenge?

Try [go](http://golang.org/).

Here's a [tech talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKnDgT73v8s) by rob pike, and here is a discussion group: http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/topics
.

Comment: Similar Q and some answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72931/whats-the-best-alternative-to-c-for-real-time-graphics-programming

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [Lua](http://www.lua.org/home.html).

Lua is a relatively tiny language which manages to be capable and universal with just a few concepts. The [BNF specification for the whole language](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#8) fits easily on one page. It has numbers, booleans, tables and functions, and surprisingly that's all the datatypes it needs. It can even work in an object-oriented fashion.

There's a compiler, Luac, that compiles Lua to bytecode.

Lua is already being used as a UI programming language for games. Addons for World of Warcraft and a few other games are programmed in Lua. I believe Lua is a very good fit for this kind of task.

You want OpenGL? OK... http://luagl.wikidot.com/ is an OpenGL library for Lua.

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't know what you want to do, I don't know what are the chances we success. Therefor, what about a language where you have to set the probability of your statement to fail :

Meet [GOTO++](http://99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-goto++-976.html).

Don't say "thanks you", it's on me.

Comment: Wow, even funnier with your question edited. Why not directly make a MMORPG ? http://metamagick.net/images/mmorpg.gif

Answer (score 0):

C++ is Great, it's not scripting lang, so you don't even need a scripting host.

Comment: He wants an easy language. I wouldn't recommend C++ to anyone not willing to invest a lot of blood, sweat and tears.